# How to check a list for greater or less than var integers

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer

```
var=42

l = [1,2,3,7,3,5,21,8,44,16,13]

if l.index(5) < l.index(var-20):
    print ("True")  

else:
    print ("False")
```

I want to pick a value (var) and test to see which comes first from the list, either var+ (for example 20), or var- (again could be 20).

The problem I am having with the above code is that if a value doesn't exist in the list, then it gives me an error telling me so.

Comment: What if neither `var+x` nor `var-x` appear in the list?

Comment: @DanielTJones So you want a value within the _**range**_ `var-x` to `var+x`?

Answer (score 3):

You need a different approach to finding the numbers, obviously.  Instead, let's try computing *once* the numbers you need to find.  Let's assume different numbers for the spans, such as 20 high (what you used) and 17 low (for sake of difference).

```
var = 42
target = [1,2,3,7,3,5,21,8,44,16,13]

lo_diff = 20
hi_diff = 17

lo_num = var - lo_diff
hi_num = var + hi_diff

# Check to see which of the two is in the list:

lo_index = target.index(lo_num) if lo_num in target else -1
hi_index = target.index(hi_num) if hi_num in target else -1
```

This leaves you with the accurate index for each value found, -1 if not found.  I expect that you can finish from here?

---

**USAGE NOTE**

Learn to *believe* in Boolean values.  Your output block should be a single statement:

```
if l.index(5) < l.index(var-20):
    print ("True")  
else:
    print ("False")
```

... reduces to ...

```
print( l.index(5) < l.index(var-20) )
```

Simply print the value of the Boolean expression.

Comment: This was perfect thank you. I also took note of the usage note too and it looks cleaner now thanks.